# Como executar uma tarefa todos os meses usando Java

Tags: java

Olá,

Gostaria de saber como posso agendar uma tarefa para ser executada todo 1 dia do mês.

Obrigado.

Comment: Nos mostre o que já tentou fazer postando seu código. Vc pode editar a pergunta e adicionar seu código nela e formatar ele também usando a opção `{}`. Faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender sobre o site.

Comment: Precisa necessariamente ser em Java? Um script simples em bat ou bash resolveria seu problema.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
boolean isFirstDay = date.getDayOfMonth() == 1;
if (isFirstDay) executaTarefa();
```

Mas aconselho fazer isso pelo sistema operacional, no Windows tem o **agendador de tarefas** e no linux temos a `crontab`. Ambos são fáceis de utilizar.

Comment: Mais se eu utilizar o"Agendador de tarefas do Windows, Eu vou conseguir executar um código dentro do meu .jar?

E esse código que tu mandou, pra mim checar com ele eu posso utilizar um Timer(), Verificando a cada 10 minutos?
Obrigado.

Comment: @SkyVox não vai não. o agendador funciona a parte dentro do windows. Essa resposta não responde ao que foi perguntado, até porque sua pergunta está ampla demais.